# any special consideration when adding more than one jQuery UI popup?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Is it allowed to have more than one popup on the page? I don't mean open simultaneously, but rather a different set of inputs?  I can get one to work, but not the second. They're both instantiated in the same manner, except the second one has `my-dialog2` for the id, pointing to a different DIV. The second DIV renders fine if I remove display: none from its CSS, so it's not malformed markup that's causing the problem. I'm thinking it might have something to do with `destroy(`). Should I be destroying the popups every time they're closed?

```
function popupEditor() {
    var popup$ = $("my-dialog");
    //popup$.dialog("destroy");
    popup$.dialog({       
        appendTo: "#my-container",
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 300,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {

            "Save": function () {
                var bValid = true;                
                if (bValid) {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }


    });

    popup$.dialog('open');
    $("#my-dialog" + " input:text:visible:first").focus();

}
```

Comment: Can you setup a demo of the issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: I've been looking at it for an hour and cannot spot my error. http://jsfiddle.net/uLjK2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uLjK2/1/ is the current one, sorry.

Comment: Found the error! It works.  http://jsfiddle.net/uLjK2/3/

Comment: You miss a # in the second dialog open

Comment: Just see now that you posted the same comment :-)